# Which Rest sharp version should I use to support a legacy .Net framework application built on version 4.6.1

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, .net-assembly, restsharp, .net-4.6

I have and application that is build using .net framework 4.6.1.0. I can't upgrade it. I have to create an assembly file for this application that gets loaded dynamically. This assembly must be able to make http request using basic, Oauth2.0 authorizations.
I would like to use rest sharp, however the latest code is moved to .Net 6. Which version of rest sharp supports .net framework 4.6.1.0 ?
Or should I look into other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

The latest RestSharp version hasn't been "moved to .NET 6". RestSharp 108 is built for .NET Standard 2.0, .NET 5 and .NET 6 targets.

[image: NuGet screenshot]

WHen using .NET Framework 4.6.1, you can install RestSharp and it will be used as a .NET Standard 2.0 library.